# Linear map in Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

If you have a linear map $h\mapsto T(h)$ from $H_1$ a real separable space, to Hilbert space $H_2$, it seem that this maps provides an isometry of $H_1$ onto a closed subspace of $H_2$. 
I try to understood this result.
The closed supspace can be $\overline{\mathrm{Im}\,\, T}$. And 
\begin{align*}
\|T(h)\|_{H_1}^2=\langle T(h), T(h) \rangle_{H_1}
\end{align*} 
I don't see where is the isometry.

Thanks for reading and helps.

Comment: Perhaps you are given that $\|T(h)\|_{H_2} = \|h\|_{H_1}$? As it stands, you have no conditions on $T$.

Comment: Exactly yes thank's !